# Suddenly unable to connect to 5GHz wifi network (PiZero)

Tags: wifi, pi-zero, raspbian-jessie

OS is Raspbian Jessie with latest updates. Everything is stock packages, no special configuration either. It just runs eJabberd at the moment.

As of a few days ago, I have stopped being able to connect to my 5GHz wireless network using my Ralink RT5572 wifi dongle. It worked fine for over 6 months.
Using the same dongle, I can connect to the 2.4GHz network just fine. However since that frequency is quite full here, I want to use the 5GHz one.

There are three other clients using the 5GHz network and all of them can still connect to it just fine.

The 2.4GHz network SSID is `WIFI_NETWORK` and the 5GHz one is `WIFI_NETWORK_5G`. The AP is my TP-Link Archer VR900v with latest official firmware. Channels are automatically selected by the AP on both networks. Both networks have WPA2 Personal (AES) set for security. Everything, even the passwords, is the same on both networks, except of course the SSID and frequencies.

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="WIFI_NETWORK_5G"
    psk="XXXXXXXX"
}
```

Now, if I try to connect to the AP on the 5GHz network, the authentication gets denied by the AP. `dmesg` shows it gets denied with `code=22`. The Internet says this means:

```
Invalid RSN information element capabilities
```

Which appears to have something to do with the encryption. The settings for that are the same for both networks, however. So that doesn't make much sense to me. The AP itself doesn't appear to log this, though.

Comment: Did this happen after an update/upgrade?

Comment: @NULL difficult to say. I update the Pi on a regular basis but it could have been offline for some time (days) without me noticing, since it isn't doing anything critical right now.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? Did you try the dongle on other machines?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this suddenly stopped working but [the following might work](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=54171&p=447476):

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree crda
```

`sudo iw reg set US` or whatever your region is

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, sadly. It has been running on the 2.4GHz band for a while now, but with bad performance due to heavy use in the area. Region is DE. The other 5GHz clients continue to work without problems.

Comment: @Anpan Just want to make sure... did you also install firmware-linux-nonfree and crda?

Comment: Indeed I did. I am almost certain that I didn't have to install firmware initially tho. The dongle worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Something overwrote your supplicant config, you need to reset it:

The configs below also set a manual IP at 192.168.1.60.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
address 192.168.1.60
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="replace_with_your_ssid"
psk="replace_with_your_password"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
group=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Then I installed wicd and wicd-curses with the following commands:

sudo apt-get install wicd
sudo apt-get install wicd-curses
Run wicd-curses at the command line and setup your wireless network and let it automatically connect to this network on startup.

Reboot and I was able to connect to my wireless network.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work either. I even checked if iwlist wlan0 scan lists those capabilities. It does and it also shows both networks with the exact same capabilities, yet refuses with code 22 on the 5GHz one. I have just about given up now.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my Pi is only able to use some of the wifi channels ([https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118213/pi-4b-wifi-can-only-use-channels-legal-in-china]) that is supposed to be legal in my country, so depending on which channel my router picked, the Pi may or may not be able to connect.

Try running `sudo iwlist wlan0 channel` to see what channels your pi supports -- if it's only some of the legal channels, maybe you can force your router to use one of the channels the Pi works with.

Comment: Can you explain why it does not work after 6 month?

Comment: First, I should have been clear that I'm not confident this is the reason for your problem, it's just one possibly you might try.  It might have failed after 6 months because you rebooted your router, and this time it happened to pick a channel that your PI doesn't see.

Answer (score -2):

Recently Raspberry Pi has some security concerns with WiFi Connection; don't know why; but there is always a solution for any problem. First of all type `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` in your RPi terminal and look if your router is listed or not. If it is listed then great and you are nearly done with setting up your network. Type `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and go to the bottom of this file and paste

```
network={
    ssid="your_ESSID_Name"
    psk="Your_wifi_password"
}
```

and leave a blank line at the end. Hint you will type both your `ssid` and `psk` between the double quotes. Now save the file by pressing `Ctrl+X` then `Y`, then finally press `Enter`. I would recommend that you type the following command to reconfigure your WiFi `sudo wpa_cli reconfigure`. You can verify that you are connected by executing `ifconfig wlan0`. If the `inet addr` field has an address beside it, the Pi has connected to the network. If not, check your `password` and `ESSID` are correct, and consider rebooting the RPi. If all the above doesn't work for you. Try checking the official RPi website for [Setting WiFi Up Via the Command Line Inteface](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).

> It would be great to try this solution on a very fresh image.