# Pi 4B wifi can only use channels legal in China

Tags: wifi, pi-4

My Raspberry Pi 4 can access some wifi channels, but not all of them.

My question is: How can I get it to access all the wifi channels it is supposed to be able to use in Canada?

It is configured for Canada:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo iw reg get
[sudo] password for pi: 
global
country CA: DFS-FCC
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
        (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
        (5470 - 5600 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
        (5650 - 5730 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
```

Canada allows the 5 GHz channels 32-165 ([with a few exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)).
The Pi, however, is missing channels 68-144:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 channel
wlan0     24 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.765 GHz (Channel 153)
```

The channels that the RPI4 supports are exactly the ones that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) says are supported in Mainland China.

My `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=CA

network={
        ssid="Printer"
        psk="************"
}
```

My /boot/octopi-wpa-supplicant.txt:

```
# Use this file to configure your wifi connection(s).
#
# Just uncomment the lines prefixed with a single # of the configuration
# that matches your wifi setup and fill in SSID and passphrase.
#
# You can configure multiple wifi connections by adding more 'network'
# blocks.
#
# See https://linux.die.net/man/5/wpa_supplicant.conf
# (or 'man -s 5 wpa_supplicant.conf') for advanced options going beyond
# the examples provided below (e.g. various WPA Enterprise setups).
#
# !!!!! HEADS-UP WINDOWS USERS !!!!!
#
# Do not use Wordpad for editing this file, it will mangle it and your
# configuration won't work. Use a proper text editor instead.
# Recommended: Notepad++, VSCode, Atom, SublimeText.
#
# !!!!! HEADS-UP MACOSX USERS !!!!!
#
# If you use Textedit to edit this file make sure to use "plain text format"
# and "disable smart quotes" in "Textedit > Preferences", otherwise Textedit
# will use none-compatible characters and your network configuration won't
# work!

## WPA/WPA2 secured
network={
  ssid="Printer"
  psk="**********"
}

## Open/unsecured
#network={
#  ssid="put SSID here"
#  key_mgmt=NONE
#}

## WEP "secured"
##
## WEP can be cracked within minutes. If your network is still relying on this
## encryption scheme you should seriously consider to update your network ASAP.
#network={
#  ssid="put SSID here"
#  key_mgmt=NONE
#  wep_key0="put password here"
#  wep_tx_keyidx=0
#}

# Uncomment the country your Pi is in to activate Wifi in RaspberryPi 3 B+ and above
# For full list see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2
#country=GB # United Kingdom
country=CA # Canada
#country=DE # Germany
#country=FR # France
#country=US # United States

### You should not have to change the lines below #####################

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Going by the system name are you running Octopi?  If so a copy of the /boot/octopi-wpa-supplicant.txt will help (assuming v0.15 or above). I guess you have CN rather than CA somewhere... I'm not sure nationality was settable before v0.15

Comment: Some two years ago I bought a 2G/5G WiFi router but was very disappointed that Rpi4B could not use 5G. I googled and found linux experts reporting the same problem: 5G is not for Rpi buster (and some other linux variants). It seems to be a firmware setting problem and unsolvable. I reported this problem twice in this forum but nobody commented on it. So I have been using Rpi4B using 2.6GH but no 5GHz WiFi for two years. Anybody found a solution, please let me (@tlfong01) know, and I am glad to update my out of date info of ***No 5GHz WiFi for Rpi***.. Much appreciated.

Comment: @tlfong01 On my Pi4 w/Buster, 5GHz WiFi worked out of the box. Could the problem be in your router?

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev, many thanks for confirming that Rpi4 w/Buster can do WiFi 5GHz out of the box. (1) As I  mentioned in my comment, I encountered the No 5GHz problem and after struggling for one or two hours, I gave up and searched rpi.org forum where I found that the cause was related to linux kernel/driver setting and no linux expert/hacker could suggest any fix. (2) Anyway, I will later try again. If it works now, then it likely that the linux kernel/driver has updated (I am not surprised because everybody then was upset!). / to continue, ...

Comment: It was two years ago, and not urgent, because I have been using 2.6GHz these two years. I will looked back my record and if I find the cause, I would let you know. Many thanks again. Cheers.